# Cannot hide exports in armeabi-v7a

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} -s")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -s")

set(sources ...)
set(includes ...)
add_library(mylib SHARED ${sources})
include_directories(${includes})
find_library(log-lib log )
target_link_libraries(test ${log-lib} )
```

When I compile my library is built successfully and when I run `file` it says library is stripped. I have used the following attribute for global variables:

```
__attribute__((visibility("hidden"))
```

But this does not seem to affect armeabi-v7a. I still see them in the libraries export symbol table for armeabi-v7a. Is there anything I can do to hide this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

> @rprichard commented on 19 Feb 2019
> This looks like the same issue as
> https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39413 / #829. `-Oz` turns on the
> GlobalMerge optimization, which isn't preserving the visibility
> attributes on variables.
>
> Adding `-mno-global-merge` to the cflags is a workaround

Source - https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/913#issuecomment-465357660